# unable to read PHP cURL result. var_dump works, but unable to pass it to variable

Tags: php, curl, header

I have cURL function which reads remote json data. It works with many servers just fine, but now I need to use it on one specific website and it does not pass data to variable. I can still var_dump it or just simply echo it and it sends me to that website.

this is my remote server side code (simple just for here):

```
<?php echo json_encode(['test'=>'test']);?>
```

this is my receiving end:

```
<?php    
        $ch = curl_init();
        $curlConfig = array(
            CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://binance99.unaux.com/index.php',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
        $r = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        print_r(json_decode($r));
?>
```

there is nothing in $r, if I var_dump($r) it redirects me to the http://binance99.unaux.com/index.php,

I tried CURLOPT_HEADER => false, also I tried SSL version of my remote website, no luck.

I also tried file_get_contents() with same results.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried checking for any errors with [`curl_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and looking at the info recieved using [`curl_getinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) ?

Comment: _"there is nothing in $r"_ - that can't be true. Outputting that "nothing", could not possibly redirect you anywhere then.  _"if I var_dump($r) it redirects me to the ..."_ - JSON can't actually "redirect" you anywhere either. So this is all the more indication, that you did not in fact get JSON back - but probably some HTML, that contains a redirect via JS or meta element. json_decode will return null, if you pass it invalid JSON.

Comment: not getting curl_error() I do get curl_info() result: attaching that as answer to question

Comment: @CBore I know json could not forward me.  I was thinking that the reply is containing some headers doing that. But even after I did disable headers, it would not get the result to the $r. If I do echo $r, I get forwarded.

Comment: so the problem is on the serving website. they wont allow cURL requests to grab the data. That is what happened.